# Add two elements in the same list and create attributes to link the two elements

Tags: java, spring-boot, sockets

I code a gateway in Java allowing to receive a frame with the following information: `ETQ | RGS | B | MESSAGE | ETX | CHECKSUM`. I would like to parse the frame to get the RGS and the message, I coded this part but I would like to add these two elements to the same list with attributes. Is this possible?

Here is my code :

```
static List<String> msgRGSLCR = new ArrayList<String>();

byte[] rgs = new byte[0];

for (int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < buffer.length; y++) {
        if (buffer[i] == 5) {
            if (buffer[y] == 0) {
                rgs = Arrays.copyOfRange(buffer, i + 1, y);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}

byte[] lcr = new byte[0];

for (int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < buffer.length; y++) {
        if (buffer[i] == 0) {
            if (buffer[y] == 3) {
                lcr = Arrays.copyOfRange(buffer, i + 1, y);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of data you working with, please? In this case, please edit your question to add it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, `HashMap` is what you are looking for.

```
var msgToRgs = new HashMap<byte[], byte[]>();
// do here you code of constructing rgs and lcr byte arrays
msgToRgs.put(rgs, lcr);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. The problem is that I need to have the duplicates (have the same keys several times in my map) is it possible?

Comment: @Gojoooo7 Generally, no, you can't have duplicate keys for any standard map. However, you can use another generic type for map. For example, try to use `HashMap<byte[], List<byte[]>>`. In this case you can store by one key several values in a single list. Also think about creating classes for claims in your frame. As a sample: class `Claim` with two fields: `byte[] payload` and `ClaimType type`, where `ClaimType` is an enum of types: ETQ | RGS | B | MESSAGE | ETX | CHECKSUM. P.S. When use a custom class for keys in any map, don't forget to override `equals` and `hashCode`